# Why is Activerecord queries returning sorted data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, has-many-through

I have the following data 
As you can see there is a Tale Model and Purpose Model and a `Has_many_through` join model `TalePurposeJoin` 
Now the join table has data as [4,3] but on query `tale.purpose_ids` I get [3,4]
I want to retain the db order. 
What is activerecord doing behind the scene, why and how do I stop it.

Here is the query sql is generating

```
SELECT "purposes".id FROM "purposes" INNER JOIN "tale_purpose_joins" ON "purposes"."id" = "tale_purpose_joins"."purpose_id" WHERE "tale_purpose_joins"."tale_id" = ?  [["tale_id", 1]]
```

[image: Joins]

Comment: can you copy/paste the queries ? I'm not able to see, as my vision is not good.

Comment: put in your question....

Comment: without an order clause the database can return rows in any order it wants.